# Как вернуть имена файлов через bash или python?

Tags: linux, файлы, имена

У меня такая проблема. Есть множество файлов, изначально у них были русские названия. Однако эти названия после перебрасывания файлов на раздел fat32 и обратно просто сломало. Причём, их вид такой:

```
 ~ $ ls
'Ð§Ñ'$'\302\202''Ð¾ Ð²Ñ'$'\302\213'' Ñ'$'\302\201''Ð´ÐµÐ»Ð°Ð»Ð¸ Ñ'$'\302\201'' Ð²Ð°Ñ'$'\302\210''ÐµÐ¸Ì'$'\302\206'' Ð¼ÐµÑ'$'\302\207''Ñ'$'\302\202''Ð¾Ð¸
 '$'\302\206''_.mp3'
```

Как такие названия файлов вообще исправлять? А у меня таких файлов целый шквал... ОС - Linux

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/convmv

Comment: попробовал. Система в упор пишет, что названия файлов якобы уже в UTF-8

Comment: Тут явно что-то ещё сломалось. Потому конвертация utf-8 → windows-1252 даёт `Ч�о в� �делали � ва�еи� ме��ои_.mp3` похоже на «Что вы сделали с вашей мечтой.mp3»

Comment: хз, у меня все отработало корректно. И да, песню вы правильно угадали :)

Comment: А просто win1252 и iso-8859-1 похожи, но немного отличаются. Про исо я вообще забыл

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему простым скриптом на Python:

```
import os

global d

for a in os.listdir("."):
    try:
        d = a.encode('iso-8859-1').decode('utf-8')
        os.rename(a, d)
    except:
        pass
```